# ElasticSearch - How can I reuse script_fields field in aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch

It is possible to use a script_field to compute a field, '**emp_salary**', and use in an aggregation query? Here's an example.

I have a script_fields script to compute the '**emp_salary**', and I want to use it in the aggregation sub query but I get

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name.keyword": "John"
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "emp_salary": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """return 1"""
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "average": {
      "avg": {
        "field": "_field['emp_salary']"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but I get null for the 'emp_salary'. Am I accessing the field value wrong?

```
"aggregations": {
    "average": {
      "value": null
    }
  }
```

Thanks